# Extract values from JavaScript object by key

Tags: javascript

I receive a JSON from a REST service which is represented by the following JavaScript object:

```
[
    {
        name: 'demo1',
        contentType: 'text/plain',
        lang: 'en-US',
        type: 'FILE',
        revision: 5
    },
    {
        name: 'demo2',
        contentType: 'text/plain',
        lang: 'en-US',
        type: 'FILE',
        revision: 29
    }
]
```

From this object I'd like to extract all values from the `name` key, i.e. in the end I have a new array with the values `[demo1, demo2]`.

I tried running a for-loop over `Object.entries()` but this seems somewaht tedious. There is probably a much easier way.

Comment: And have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: A simple map()....

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map()` and an arrow function.

```js
const theArray = [
    {
        name: 'demo1',
        contentType: 'text/plain',
        lang: 'en-US',
        type: 'FILE',
        revision: 5
    },
    {
        name: 'demo2',
        contentType: 'text/plain',
        lang: 'en-US',
        type: 'FILE',
        revision: 29
    }
]

console.log(theArray.map(obj => obj.name))
```

Comment: This is an often-asked duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array).